# How to remove blog name from wp_title by using filter hook

Tags: php, wordpress

When we use wp_title(); function it automatically shows the blog name and separator. I want to know that is there any way to remove blog name and show only title by using wordpress filter hook ?

Here is my code

```
public function title(){
            return "My Customized Title";        
}
add_filter('wp_title', 'title',15, 3);
```

and this is in my theme's header.php

```
<title><?php wp_title( '-', true, 'left' ); ?></title>
```

This code is returning the "My Customized TitleBlog Name"

I have googled alot but didn't solution is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Can you just try with `wp_title();` ?

Answer (score 0):

Place the following code in your function.php customize title for specific page as per your requirements.

```
public static function page_title(){
    global $paged;

    if (function_exists('is_tag') && is_tag()) {
        single_tag_title("Tag Archive for &quot;"); echo '&quot; - '; }
    elseif (is_category()) {
        wp_title(''); echo ' - '; }
    elseif (is_archive()) {
        wp_title(''); echo ' Archive - '; }
    elseif (is_search()) {
        echo 'Search for &quot;'.wp_specialchars($s).'&quot; - '; }
    elseif (!(is_404()) && (is_single()) || (is_page())) {
        wp_title(''); echo ' - '; }
    elseif (is_404()) {
        echo '404 Not Found - '; }
    if (is_home()) {
        bloginfo('name'); echo ' - '; bloginfo('description'); }
    else {
        bloginfo('name'); }
    if ($paged>1) {
        echo ' - page '. $paged; }
}
```

And then use

```
<title><?php page_title() ?></title>
```